# Why change height and width values in JFrame on minimize and maximize and resize in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working on a project in java and i have some problem about jframes. I just create a jframe in netbeans and this frame has one jlabel. I am resize this label on formWindowOpened Event something like below.

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){                                  
   label.setSize(200, 200);
}
```

But problem is that when I resize or minimize or maximize my jframe then label automatically resize to its default size. Now tell me where I am going wrong.

This is form load picture and its size is `200X200`:

[image: This is form load picture]

This is when the frame is resized:

[image: This is when the frame is resized]

Answer (score 0):

Swing is designed to be used with "layout managers". Each component is responsible for determining its own "preferred size". The layout manager will then use this information to determine the size/location of every component added to the panel.

When the frame is resized, the layout manager is invoked so your setSize(...) statement is ignored because the layout manager will reset the size.

Why are you trying to assign a random size to a label? The size of the label should be determined by the text and/or Icon added to the label. Let the layout manager to its job.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.